# Extract name field from array<struct>

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, explode

Please i need help.
I have a df in pyspark

[image]
I need "explode" the "atributos" field, but i need this fields:

```
name_of_atribute, value_of_atribute
bikes, 0
bags, 0
suitcases, 0
```

Then the result df would be:

```
edad, genero, es_prm, atributos, name_of_atribute, value_of_atribute (etc).
```

When I explode the "atributos" field i get 3 new fields

```
bikes, bags, suitcases
0, 0, 0
```

But I also need other field, the "name_of_atribute".

Sorry for may bad english and I hope someone can help me.

I tried with this:

```
df2 = df.explode("atributos").alias("atributo")
```

but the result is not what I want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, i need new fields with the data in the "atributos" field.

In the example of the image, i need this: (two new fields name and value)

tipo_paso, edad, genero, es_prm, atributos, name_atributo, value_atributo

The values of this fields would be (in this case 3 new register one by atributos value):

S, null, null, 0, bikes, 0

S, null, null, 0, bags, 0

S, null, null, 0, suitcases, 0


I hope this help you.
Thanks

Comment: @tempo Added my answer, let me know if the requirement is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
df.withColumn("atributos", F.explode("atributos"))\
  .select("*", F.explode(F.from_json(F.to_json("atributos"), 'map<string, string>')).alias("name_of_atribute", "value_of_atribute"))\
  .drop("atributos")\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|tipo_paso|atributos                               |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|S        |[{suitcase -> 0, bikes -> 0, bags -> 0}]|
+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
|tipo_paso|name_of_atribute|value_of_atribute|
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
|S        |suitcase        |0                |
|S        |bikes           |0                |
|S        |bags            |0                |
+---------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Ronak Jain,

Works!!!! 

Many, many thanks!!!

Comment: @tempo Glad! Consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)